# How does vim set indentation for json files?

Tags: vim, neovim

Other files, like .c, .cpp, .java, etc., I like to indent 4 spaces, but with only .json files, I like to indent 2 spaces.

How can I configure vim for this purpose?

I know it's possible to do :!%jq . to format the entire json file, but what I want is the automatic indentation set specifically for the json file instead of manually entering instructions to format the file.

Comment: See `:help ftplugin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `tabstop` via `:autocmd`.

```
" Sets the indent length for all files.
:set tabstop=2
" If the file type is the specified type, change to the specified indent length.
:autocmd FileType json,html,xml,yaml set tabstop=2
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [`coc-json`](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) of [`coc.nvim`](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim). And I use

```json
    "coc.preferences.formatOnSaveFiletypes": [
        "json"
    ],
```

in my `coc-settings.json` which can be opened by `:CocConfig` command. It will auto format the json file with 2 space indents before saving file.